# 'Titanium.API.INFO' is not displaying in console

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

I am using Windows 7.

but `Ti.API.INFO` not displaying in `console`. I changed log level also but still its not display in console can some one help how to show info..

Android device is working fine but not displaying INFO in it also.

and emulator is not launching also.

`Ti.API.info('splash function run');`

Comment: Testing on device or emulator?

Comment: sorry see this again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can find your answer in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10724292/titanium-api-info-never-shows-anything-in-the-console)

Now, my 2 cents, sometimes there is a problem running the emulator when you have your phone plugged at the same time. You could try unplugging your device first.

But perhaps, debugging with the emulator isn't what you want. I recommend to start the `ddms` tool. And use a query to search what you need, like one of these: `tag:ti`, `tag:tia`, `tag:tiapi`

In order to do that, open a terminal and go to your android sdk folder, cd tools, and run `ddms` command. You can find where is your android sdk folder looking into Titanium Studio -> Preferences -> Studio -> Platforms -> Android.

**Edit**

Another option is to run titanium commands from a terminal pointing to your project folder:

```
cd "path/to/your/project/folder"
# in case of using the emulator
ti build -p android
# in case of using your device
ti build -p android -T device
```

Comment: "You can find where is your android sdk folder looking into Titanium Studio -> Preferences -> Studio -> Platforms -> Android". From there it should be on tools folder. You can try to search it on windows explorer search bar: `ddms.bat`

Comment: ohhh that i missed it really,
I think it should placed in titanium only.

Comment: can you acknowledge me ?? :)

Answer (score 0):

Android device does not show console on titanium for seeing the result on android one possible solution could be alert that results

```
alert('I am alert');
```

Thanks

Comment: You are right but i am running in emulator in that also it is not displaying log `INFO`